# Should I use a UITableView or UICollectionView to create this

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I would like to create the following, but not absolutely sure which one is the best to use: UITableView or UICollectionView?

[image: table]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table views only do a single vertical list of cells. If you need a grid with rows and columns then you need a collection view.

If the 3 parts of your A-G rows are separate sections of single items then you might use a table view. (Say the left column contains an image, the middle column contains a title and subheading, and the right column contains a description of the item.)